# How can I trim double quotes from the start and end of a string in VB?

Tags: string, vb.net, trim

I receive a string which sometimes has double-quotes at the start and/or end. I need the string without the quotes. I tried following the C# code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76171408), but that doesn't compile:

```vb
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim text As String = """Text"""
        Console.WriteLine("Original value: " & text)

        Dim trimmed As String = text.Trim('"')
        Console.WriteLine("Trimmed value: " & trimmed)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Without the last two lines, this prints:

```
Original value: "Text"
```

I want the final code to print:

```
Original value: "Text"
Trimmed value: Text
```

The compile-time error I receive is:

> Program.vb(9,55): error BC30198: ')' expected.

(Line 9 is the `Trim` call.)

How should I change my code to compile and trim the quotes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C#, `"` doesn't need to be escaped in [character literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char).

The syntax for [VB character literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/constant-and-literal-data-types) is a bit different. It's like a string literal, but with a `C` suffix. To use a double-quote, you need to double it in the character literal, just like in the string literal. Here's your original example, but fixed:

```vb
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim text As String = """Text"""
        Console.WriteLine("Original value: " & text)
        
        Dim trimmed As String = text.Trim(""""C)
        Console.WriteLine("Trimmed value: " & trimmed)
        
    End Sub
End Module
```

The output is now as desired.

Note that this *won't* help with double-quotes within the string though, as `Trim` only looks at the start and end. To remove *all* double-quotes, you should use `String.Replace` instead. Here's an example:

```vb
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main(args As String())
        Dim text As String = """Before middle quote""After middle quote"""
        Console.WriteLine("Original value: " & text)

        Dim trimmed As String = text.Trim(""""C)
        Console.WriteLine("Trimmed value: " & trimmed)

        Dim replaced As String = text.Replace("""", "")
        Console.WriteLine("Replaced value: " & replaced)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Output:

```
Original value: "Before middle quote"After middle quote"
Trimmed value: Before middle quote"After middle quote
Replaced value: Before middle quoteAfter middle quote
```

Of course, you could replace the double-quote with a string, or a single quote instead.

Answer (score 4):

In VB it was annoying remembering how many quotes to use.  I found ControlChars.Quote handy.

```
    Dim text As String = """Text"""
    text = text.Trim(ControlChars.Quote)
```